# Is it possible to use Dynamic Query in JPA?

Tags: spring, jpa

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Genj.jpg

For example. Like this.
I know column = :#{#first.trait} is possible but I'd like to use some variable as column
please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. You can apply `Specification`. Take a look at the example below.

```java
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<User> {
    default Optional<User> findByColumnName(String column, String value) {
        return userRepo.findOne((Root<ProductCategory> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) -> {
          return builder.equal(root.get(column), value);
      });
    }
}
```